# Bring accountability "on" or "to" the internet?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am writing a sentence and slightly confused if I should use on or to. Which one is correct:

> The synergy between technology and policy is particularly crucial to bring accountability *to* the internet.
>
> The synergy between technology and policy is particularly crucial to bring accountability *on* the internet.

Comment: A quick Google Ngram check: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bring+accountability+to%2C+bring+accountability+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2):

Someone is accountable *to* someone, and *for* something, as a general rule. Because your verb is "bring", I think "to" makes more sense. Although we colloquially say we are "on" the Internet, bringing accountability is something done TO it, not ON it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one is totally incorrect, but "to" seems more likely.
"Bring accountability to the internet" means the internet, as a whole, lacks accountability, and one is adding it.

"Bring accountability on the internet" might be more focused on accountability itself, with the internet just being a tool you are using to bring accountability.